# which opensource loadbalancer support SPDY?

Tags: http, nginx, haproxy, spdy

I know NginX SPDY support is still in development. Are there any opensource loadbalancers out there that support it already?

Answer (score 0):

With [mod_spdy](https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/) you can have SPDY support in Apache and Apache can function as a loadbalancer.

Personally I would wait 2 months and/or help with the Nginx SPDY support.

Comment: I love nginx as much as anyone, but don't discount the fact that mod_spdy is already operational and well tested -- the latest release works great. Also, on a more pedantic note: apache, nginx, etc, offer much more than just load balancing (they're reverse proxies). AFAIK, there are no pure "spdy load balancers" out there today, unless you're willing to roll your own.

Comment: @igrigorik: I love Apache as an Application Server, more so than Nginx. But when it comes to static hosting and/or load balancing I do prefer Nginx. It all depends on your use-case of course, I just do not see Apache as the load balancer of choice.

Comment: @WoLpH & igrigorik: if your concern are static assets you could also host them in a separated server with nginx and use Apache as your application server.

Answer (score 0):

[Haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) 1.5 supports spdy. Together with jetty 9.1 this makes a killer combo.